# query returns none when querying by icontains

Tags: django

I've got a Customer model that has a field 'name'.

I've got an instance of that Customer model where the name field is equal to 'John Smith'

The following query returns None and I'm not sure why.

```
qs = Customer.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains="John Smith"))
```

The following query does return the customer

```
qs = Customer.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains="John"))
```

Any thoughts as to why the first queryset returns None?

Thanks!

Comment: As of right now, your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please check that the name saved is actually "John Smith" and not something else.

Comment: Hi Caleb, it is, in fact, saved as John Smith

Comment: Can you update showing your Customer model?  When trying your code as is, I can't reproduce this problem, so there must be something important that is missing.

Comment: Also you should try deleting and recreating that user, then show the create statement you used.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try again and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I had the name backwards in the field. It was Smith John

Comment: At least you figured it out xD

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had the name backwards in the field. It was Smith John